# NetLogo error with GIS:TURTLE-DATASET in exporting turtle coordinates

Tags: gis, netlogo

This is my first post here so apologies if formatting is bad. 
I am attempting to export the coordinates of my turtles with the GIS extension and I keep getting the same runtime error. I've scoured the internet and forums to see if anyone else has had this problem and I can't seem to find any answer. 
Here is the relevant parts of my code:

```
to go 
 ;pheasants do stuff 
 if (week = 26 and day = 7) 
 [ export-males 
   export-females ] 
end 

to export-males 
 let male-spatial gis:turtle-dataset male-pheasants 
 gis:store-dataset male-spatial (word "base_spatial/male_" year) 
end 

to export-females
 let female-spatial gis:turtle-dataset female-pheasants 
 gis:store-dataset female-spatial (word "base_spatial/female_" year) 
end
```

I am able to run this code and get output the very first time it is run, but after that initial output, it stops working. I've also examined the shape files that get exported from the very first run, and the coordinates come out well and everything looks correct so I know the issue isn't with setting the world envelope. When it hits year 1 (the second time to export), the model stops and I get the following error: 
    Extension exception: null 
    error while observer running GIS:TURTLE-DATASET

Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks!